# Restore Visual Studio 2008 Window State

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Is there an add in or some way to save and restore the current Window configuration?

For example, when I am debugging X, I want files A, B, and C open. When I am debugging Y, I want D, E and F open.

Stepping through the code results in more files sometimes being open if I selected "Step Into", etc. I would like a quick way to return to showing my core files A, B, C or D, E and F.

Is there a way to do this, eiether natively in VS or with some utility?

Comment: That's why VS supports writing macros.

Comment: an Add In or Macro will do. I'm hoping someone already wrote it.